# How to change the linespace in the TableViewCell

Tags: ios, line, tableview, cell, space

Everyone, I need insert some texts to the tableView cell. But i don't know how to change the linespace. So it looks ugly. Because every line too close. Please help me. Thanks very very much!

```
//texts
UITextView *hisText = [[UITextView alloc] init];
hisText.frame = CGRectMake(100, 110, 600, 300);
[hisText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14]];
hisText.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
hisText.editable = NO;

switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        hisText.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.";
        hisImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1928-1.jpg"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:hisText];
        //[cell.contentView addSubview:hisImg];
        break;
    case 1:
        hisText.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.";
        [cell.contentView addSubview:hisText];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: can U give the screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the length of all your text will fit in that UITextView frame you create, then you can simply do this in heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
      return 110; //you can set to whatever height you wish if you want some 'padding'
 }
```

HOWEVER, one correct way to do this so that it will fit any length of text would be to create the UITableView in heightForRow and size it properly to fit the text (perhaps using sizeToFit) and then taking it's tableView.frame.size.height and returning that value for the tableView row height.

Something like:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   UITextView *hisText = [[UITextView alloc] init];
   hisText.frame = CGRectMake(100, 110, 600, 300);
   [hisText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14]];

   switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        hisText.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium    adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.";
         [hisText sizeToFit];
         break;
    case 1:
        hisText.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.";
        [hisText sizeToFit];
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    float theHeight = hisText.frame.size.height;

    return theHeight;

}
```

Comment: thank you very much, but when i try to"return hisText.frame.size.height",it show "Returning 'CGFloat'(aka 'float')from a function with incompatible result type 'UITableView'*",

Comment: edited the code above. give that a try. added float theHeight =

Answer (score 0):

1) Instead of UITextView take UILabel and as per size of the text adjust the frame of UILabel.

Now if you want line space increase the frame of UILabel as per your requirement, it will give you space between the lines.

2) Or take UIWebeview instead of UITextView and in that you can provide line space as per HTML body.

Comment: thanks very much. but if i use the UILabel instead of UITextView. i have a lot of word in the tableview cell,i need Spend a lot of time to do that. T。T. and i don't know how to use UIWebView in the tableview cell.

Comment: Write the content what you want display in HTML file. Then load HTML file in UIWebView. with applying all your requirements like Space, Font, Color and etc.

Comment: ok. i have try another way ,it works, the code below:            NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 10.0f;
    paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 20.0f;
    paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 20.0f;
    NSString *string = @".....";
    NSDictionary *ats = @{
                          NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
                          };
    hisText.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:ats];

Answer (score 0):

U can increase the height of the row.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return [indexPath row]+110;
}
```

Here , [indexPath row]- has the default value of the rowheight

Comment: thanks very much ,now i know how to change the height of row, but i don't know how to modify the line space between the lines.